# How to add a generator to your Crystal Config file?

Tags: express, code-generation

I would like to add the `express` generator to my project using Crystal. How do I add it to my Crystal Config file?

Answer (score 0):

Generators are added to your Crystal Config file via the `generators` array.

Each generator is added by name. For `express`, you would do:

```
generators:
    express:
        version: latest
```

There are several options available including:

- `pass` - when making generators, this option allows you to pass this generator to a dependent
- `path` - specify the output path relative to the project's path
- `spec` - additional spec that is specific to each generator
- `version` - the version of the generator you wish to use

When you add a new generator to your project, you can run the following to install:

```
crystal update
```